# Update javascript array with settimeout and json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an PHP file that automatically search a directory for png files. This file is called update.php. This file contains an array ($files) with this images.

Now I get this array in javascript with json_encode, and this is working fine. 
Every minute there is a new image in my directory. But when I am using autorefresh with settimeout, then the array not updating.

> Script:

```
function vulArray() {
    for (k=0; k<dataArray.length; k++) {
        imagesArray[k].setMap(null);
    }

    // data arrays leeg gooien
    dataArray.splice(0,dataArray.length); // data array leeggooien
    imagesArray.splice(0,imagesArray.length); // oude array leegmaken

    dataArray = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>; // php array omzetten naar javascript array

    var overlayOpts = {opacity:0.0} // Standaard dekking op 0 zetten

    // data array vullen met nieuwe data
    for (k=0; k<dataArray.length; k++) { // loop starten
        var url = dataArray[k]; // images uit de dataarray toewijzen
        image = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(url, borders, overlayOpts); // nieuwe laag aanmaken
        image.setMap(map); // imagelaag op de map zetten
        imagesArray.push(image); // imagelaag in de array pushen
    }

    refreshImage = setTimeout(function() {
        DownloadUrl("update.php", vulArray);
    }, 15000); // 5 minuten = 300000
}
```

> The DownloadUrl function:

```
function DownloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
```

The file is executed every 15 seconds, this is working fine, but nothing will be updates for some sort of reason. Im emptying the arrays in the beginning of the function, but it still outputs the same array.

Comment: Can you provide `DownloadUrl` function code ?

Comment: Just added it ;) Was forgotten srry

Comment: `dataArray = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;` won't get evaluated...

Comment: sorry, what do you mean to evaluate

Comment: PHP code will not be executed in this context.

Comment: ehm, strange when i comment it out, my script doesnt work anymore.  It will retrieve images from the php array into javascript on loading the site, but nog on the auto refresh!

Comment: It gets evaluated (read: executed) only _once_, when your PHP script that outputs this piece of JavaScript runs. After that, you have the result as a _static_ value inside your JS code, that doesn’t change any more.

Comment: Okay thanks, what is the best i can do now ?

Comment: Request the new data from the server in JSON format, and then use that in your function – either by assigning it to a global variable first, or by passing it into it as a parameter …

Comment: Maybe you have an example of how to do that ?

Comment: I have done it with a AJAX function with settimeout. Data as JSON. With this it was not needed to use the json_encode anymore and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!